# Send Arguments to Python from C++/CLI

Tags: python, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a Python function in file query.py which is like this:

```
def dr2_query(ra=None, dec=None, obj='TEST', filename=None, radius=17):
```

I am trying to call this from C++/CLI like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo^ psi = gcnew ProcessStartInfo();
psi->FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\python.exe";
String^ script = "C:\\ProgramData\\Astrowerks\\CCDLABx64\\query.py";
String^ cval1 = "text1";
String^ cval2 = "text2";
String^ object = "test";
String^ filename = "c:\\test.txt";
String^ radius = "17";

psi->Arguments = String::Format(script + " {0} {1} {2} {3} {4}", cval1, cval2, object, filename, radius);

Process^ proc = ::Diagnostics::Process::Start(psi);
```

However when I run it it gives an error of "unrecognized arguments" from Python. How do I send the arguments correctly to the Python function?

Answer (score 0):

That error is being output by the Python script, specifically from its use of [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html#the-basics). (Note the error message in that example is the same as yours.)

Run `query.py -h` to see how you should be passing arguments.